# Having issue with for-loop in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop

I am trying to iterate over an array of ViewControllers in Swift, but unfortunately I am getting compilation errors that I don't understand.  Here is my relevant code:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "You have an error.", preferredStyle: .Alert)

let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default) { (action:UIAlertAction!) in
    print("you have pressed OK button");
    //below is my loop causing me trouble
    for (i in 0..< self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count) {
        if (self.navigationController?.viewControllers[i].isKindOfClass(MyViewController) == true) {
            self.navigationController?.popToViewController(self.navigationController!.viewControllers[i] as! MyViewController, animated: true)

            break;
        }
    }
}
alertController.addAction(OKAction)

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion:nil)
```

However, I keep getting errors from Xcode asking me to insert "," as a separator in my for loop statement.  Can anyone see what it is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @EricAya `== true` actually makes some sense with optional booleans, however it's still probably better to use `??` but that's just a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using a numeric for loop, why don't you use for... in syntax?

```
if let navController = self.navigationController {
  for aVC in navController.viewControllers {
    if aVC..isKindOfClass(MyViewController) {
      navController.popToViewController(aVC, animated: true)
      break
    }
  }
}
```

I used optional binding to collapse the `self.navigationController?` into navController, and for...in syntax.

Also, I don't think you need to cast your view controller to your `MyViewController` class since all you are doing with it is sending it to the popToViewController function, which takes ANY `UIViewController`.

### EDIT:

If you need the index for the items in your array, you can use the `enumerate` function on your array, which returns a set of tuples:

```
for (index, aVC) in navController.viewControllers.enumerate() {
  //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: This is the most straight-forward and correct way to go about it unless you actually need access to the index variable itself.

Comment: And if you want the index index as well you can use `for (index, aVC) in navController.viewControllers.enumerate()`

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the brackets from your for loop and add proper spacing between `0` and `self`:-

```
for i in 0 ..< self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count {
                    if(self.navigationController?.viewControllers[i].isKindOfClass(MyViewController) == true) {

                        self.navigationController?.popToViewController(self.navigationController!.viewControllers[i] as! MyViewController, animated: true)

                        break;
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Inconsistent spacing around `..<`.

You have to choose either `0 ..< self.` or `0..<self.`, otherwise the operator will be considered a prefix/postfix operator and not an infix one.

Also, the `for-in` is composed from two expressions:

```
for expr1 in expr2
```

therefore you cannot wrap the keyword `in` into parenthesis with them:

```
for i in (0 ..< self.navigationController?.viewControllers.count) {
```

Comment: That still outputs an error to insert a comma., you need to remove the brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the brackets from your `for-in` loop, the extra space in `0..< self..` and consider unwrap the value of optional count in the chain.